# Check for an active login session in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, signalr

I want to limit the login of an account to (1) only making another instance of the login to logout automatically as soon as the new instance happened, what is the most efficient way on checking if the user has an active login session?

- Record login details to the database?
- Using Third Party Library?
- Check if the identity is existing in the server side?

I am really not sure so having at least a hint would be very much help to me.

Comment: Any of your suggestions would work, I think the thing to bear in mind is that most services that have this feature (such as game developers Blizzard for example) have a slight delay between logging a user back out. Either way there are two main considerations. Firstly that a user has logged in, and secondly that they are active (If they are not active, you'd expect the application to log them out and free up the ability to log back in on another device etc.). If you can account for that, then you'll have the design for your solution.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I’ll keep that in mind especially the validation whether the user is active or not, thanks!